# Loosing jQuery styling in table with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-styling

I have a **paginated table** with some prices in it. I would like to **highlight the lowest price** in the table. 
My prices are located in the 6,7 and 8th columns. I need to evaluate each row. The script does a wonderful job, but unfortunately when I move to another page the **styling is lost**.
I suppose I have to use jQuery on() Method, but since I am very new to javascript and jQuery it is a mystery to me.

So far I am using this code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var vals = $('td:nth-child(6),td:nth-child(7),td:nth-child(8)', this).map(function() {
      return parseFloat($(this).text(), 10) ? parseFloat($(this).text(), 10) : null;
    }).get();
    // then find their minimum
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

    // tag any cell matching the min value
    $('td:nth-child(6),td:nth-child(7),td:nth-child(8)', this).filter(function() {
      return parseFloat($(this).text(), 10) === min;
    }).addClass('alert alert-success');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is because your code only runs when the page loads. You need to also execute it when the page changes. How you do that depends on the code you've written to paginate the table, which you've not shown.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 
I am using PDOCrud. I haven't written the pagination myself.